# How to reset the context menu in VisualStudio to have default items?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

Am using VisualStudio 2013, update2. I am facing the below issue when I opened a project in VisualStudio today, I noticed **on right clicking a project in the SolutionExplorer the context menu have a lot of options** that even have scrolling now. Now I have to scroll down everytime to build or clean a project.

[image]

Earlier it was like a short menu like below.

[image]

I have not changed any settings but don't know why am facing this issue. I tried to customize the context menu command and chose (Project and solution context menus | Project) from the drop down, but that didn't worked out as it is automatically reset to tfs on clicking the close button. Does any one have idea about how to rectify this?

Note: The context menu has changed only for the projects inside the solution. On right clicking the solution name in solution explorer, I am still getting the same old menu.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your context menu screenshot, it looks like you have some extensions installed that have introduced these commands. Try disabling some or all of them in Tools > Extensions and Updates Manager to see which ones belong to which extension. There unfortunately isn't a way right now to customize this context menu.

Thanks,
Cathy
Visual Studio IDE Team